# PHP MySql Insert statement using only variables

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I've been trying for the last couple of hours to write a proper insert statement using my variables. I am supposed to use a form to make a table and insert data into it. I'm also relatively new to php. I've been encountering the "NOTHING INSERTED" message each time i've tried.

### My php code

```
if (isset($_POST['INSERT'])) {      

    $table = $_POST['table'];
    $primarykey = $_POST['primarykey'];
    $field1 = $_POST['field1'];
    $field2 = $_POST['field2'];
    $field3 = $_POST['field3'];
    $fieldint = $_POST['fieldint'];
    $fieldint2 = $_POST['fieldint2'];
    $fieldint3 = $_POST['fieldint3'];

    $inprimarykey = $_POST['inprimarykey'];
    $infield1 = $_POST['infield1'];
    $infield2 = $_POST['infield2'];
    $infield3 = $_POST['infield3'];
    $infieldint = $_POST['infieldint'];
    $infieldint2 = $_POST['infieldint2'];
    $infieldint3 = $_POST['infieldint3'];

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table ($primarykey,$field1,$field2,$field3,$fieldint,$fieldint2,$fieldint3) VALUES ('$inprimarykey','$infield1','$infield2','$infield3','$infieldint','$infieldint2','$infieldint3')",$conn) or die ("NOTHING INSERTED");
}
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: Does the table exist where you are trying to insert data?

Comment: First of all please leave using mysql_* because they are officially deprecated. use mysqli_* or PDO. also just try to write die(mysql_error($conn)).

Comment: i would put the query string in to its own variable, then you can echo it out, there is a good change the error would be obvious after you did that

Comment: Have you tried echoing the query you're generating with this code? You're not [sanitizing your data](http://www.bobby-tables.com/) so any bad data will go straight into your query.

Comment: Yes the table exists, i created the table (i verified it) , the coloumns and everything were made through the variables but nothing is inserted.

Comment: you must stop using mysql_* functionswhich are deprecated for a long time. use PDO or mysqli_.    And just suggestion if you have such issue during developing and/or debug process, try to simplify everything. in your case start just from one field. if it is successful - add another one, so this way you can find the problem much faster

Comment: `or die ("NOTHING INSERTED")` isn't helping you. [Do this....](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30088679/php-mysql-insert-statement-using-only-variables#comment48290465_30088679) or keep digging. You're behind your computer, we're not.

Comment: Thank you, i'll get to testing it out now.

Comment: @Fred-ii- speak for yourself, im hiding in his closet.

Comment: @Dagon See if my jacket's in there, will ya? thanks ;-)

Comment: As @anant and Alex have suggested, please do yourself a favor and learn how to use mysqli_ and prepared statements. Here's the documentation ... http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Yeah i understand, but i still need help with the insert statment, i just want to know if i have written it properly considering i only used variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should not use anymore the `mysql_` functions, but instead the `mysqli_` functions.

Also you are not escaping your user input for any malicious code you should use `mysqli_real_escape_string`.

I'm sorry, but I rewrote your code. I use the class `Mysqli` to create the connection. Also in case of an error it will output the output that `MySQL` returns:

```
    if (isset($_POST["INSERT"])) {
        $conn = new Mysqli( 'localhost', 'username', 'password', 'db-name' );
        $table=$conn->real_escape_string( $_POST['table'] );

        $data = array(
            $_POST['primarykey'] => $conn->real_escape_string( $_POST['inprimarykey'] ),
            $_POST['field1'] => $conn->real_escape_string( $_POST['infield1'] ),
            $_POST['field2'] => $conn->real_escape_string( $_POST['infield2'] ),
            $_POST['field3'] => $conn->real_escape_string( $_POST['infield3'] ),
            $_POST['fieldint'] => $conn->real_escape_string( $_POST['infieldint'] ),
            $_POST['fieldint2'] => $conn->real_escape_string( $_POST['infieldint2'] ),
            $_POST['fieldint3'] => $conn->real_escape_string( $_POST['infieldint3'] )
        ); 
        $query = sprintf( "INSERT INTO %s (`%s`) VALUES('%s');", $table, implode( '`,`', array_keys( $data ) ), implode( "','", $data ) );
        if( $conn->query( $query ) === false ) {
            printf("Error: %s\n", $conn->error);
        }
    }
```

Let me know if this helps you out.